# Java find object reference

Tags: java

I have panel with more buttons of ButtonClass with different names. How can i find out when i click the finish button on which button i clicked first(which object of ButtonClass) and also modify his name ?

```
public class ButtonClass extends JButton{
    public String name;

    public ButtonClass(String name){
            this.name = name;
            this.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");
            finish.addActionListener(new Finish());
            panel.add(finish);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setFocusable(false);
            frame.setSize(1600,900);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

And the other actionListner i am trying to create for the finish button :

```
public class Finish  implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Here
    }
}
```

So basically i have `ButtonClass button1 = new ButtonClass("Button1"); button2, etc ;`  So when i click on one of them , a frame will open with another jbutton called finish . When i click on that i want to modify the name of my ButtonClass which was clicked in the first place.

Comment: I still don't quit understand what your asking

Comment: I need to modify the ButtonClass jbutton's name when i click of the finish button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your action listener class to keep a reference to the button, like:

```
public class Finish  implements ActionListener {

    ButtonClass button;

    public Finish( ButtonClass button ) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Now you can use the field button when you get a click
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll also have to modify the button preparation:

```
JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");
finish.addActionListener(new Finish((ButtonClass)e.getSource()));
```

Note that I'm passing `e.getSource()` to the `Finish` constructor. It gives you the source of the click in `ButtonListener`, and you pass that down to the `Finish` object.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you're trying to determine which button was pressed and change its text depending on the button.

So the way that you would do this is in your event listener, in the action performed method, you first need to get the source of the press. In this case you would do that by doing

```
Object source = e.getSource ();
```

This will give you the button, in your case, that was pressed. So all you have to do is check if the source is equal to one of your buttons and set the text.

```
if (source == myFirstJButton) {
    ButtonClass btn = (ButtonClass) source
    //set text here
} else if (source == mySecondJButton) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This will give me the source of the finish button .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're extending to specific type of buttons already why not just do this for the Finish button and include a property for the 'finish creator' button.

```
public class FinishButton extends JButton{
    public ButtonClass creator;

    public FinishButton (ButtonClass creator){
            this.creator= creator;
            this.addActionListener(new Finish());
    }
}
```

Then your ButtonListener becomes

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        FinishButton finish = new FinishButton((ButtonClass) e.getSource());
        panel.add(finish);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        frame.setSize(1600,900);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

then do what you will with `finish.creator` such as

```
public class Finish  implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FinishButton source = (FinishButton) e.getSource();
        source.creator.name = "Whatever";
        //etc
    }
}
```